# struts2 textfield tag throws exception

Tags: struts2

what is the reason behind the exception in struts2 jsp page? it throws following  exception : Unterminated <s:textfield tag

```
<s:textfield name="createdDate" id="createdDate" cssClass="form-control width-xs" value="<s:property value="%{createdDate}"/>" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not put one struts tag inside another which causes the exception

> `value="<s:property value="%{createdDate}"/>"`

you can do it like this

> `value="%{createdDate}"`

Comment: thanks Viraj!! it worked. and i learned.:)

Comment: when you have received an answer you are happy with, please accept it by clicking the tick/check next to the answer. That way the answerer gets rewarded for providing the correct answer, and you get points added to your reputation and an improved accept ratio, making people more likely to want to answer your questions in future :)